# Apache commons.net.ftpclient on Linux

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

I am using org.apache.commons.net.FTPClient to upload/download/list files using FTP. The server daemon is vsftpd running on CentOS 5.4, and the apache package is 2.0

It seems that all the mentioned operations perform well on the server (judging by the log vsftpd.log) where files are uploaded, the download command is received, so does the list command. The  problem is that the client deadlocks, so it never acknowledges the operation end. Same code works fine when connecting to an FTP server that is running on WindowsXP. Not sure what to do

Changing the OS key with the FTPClientConfig from UNIX to NT or WINDOWS does not seem to change that behavior. I've also tried with PASIV/ACTIVE mode ftp client, without any success though

I am hoping someone could help me with this. Thanks

Peter

Comment: Just an observation that, with a FTP client such as ncftp running on the same client machine as my application (that I am complaining about) I can upload/download and list files in the FTP server no problem

Comment: It seems that in passive mode the client does connect and never deadlock

Comment: I used to have same exact problem with FTP on Fedora 11 server. I disabled FTP altogether and switched to SFTP, works like a charm. Little slower that FTP, but works.